# Python | How to fix the error "NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/bin/python3/site-packages'"

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip

I am using macOS Big Sur and I've been having a problem with installing any python packages for a couple of days now. This error happens everytime I try to install or uninstall a python package.

I have tried using `sudo` as well, but the error persists. Another solution that I have tried was to change the PATH variable to add the /usr/local/bin folder before the /usr/bin one, which contains brew's installation of python3, however that didn't help either.

Do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: can you `ls /usr/bin/python3/`  what is site-packages?  Is it a file?  A link?  I would think if it was simply missing it would say FileNotFound.

Comment: The output of that command is the following: `ls: /usr/bin/python3/: Not a directory` because it is a file.

Comment: @loanaDumil: Ah, got it.  Assumed site-packages was the non-directory, but that makes more sense.

Comment: @saquintes - yes I should have been more explicit :)

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the site-packages directory, by executing from command line:

```
python -c 'import site; print(site.getsitepackages())'
['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/site-python', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: I have located the site-packages directory, but when installing a package using pip, it doesn't look into that directory, instead it tries to look for `/usr/bin/python3/site-packages`, which doesn't exist because `/usr/bin/python3` is a file, not a folder.